# WPF setting a border on a button to fade in and out

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

Im trying to get my button border to fade in and out. I have the effect but its applying it to the whole button and not the border.

App.xamml:

```
<Style x:Key="PassiveGlow"     
  BasedOn="{StaticResource GlowingButton}"  
  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">   

   <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
      <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" 
            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
      </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Button XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="LoginButton"
    Padding="5"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="0,10,0,0"
    Width="100"
    Content="Login"
    ToolTipService.ShowDuration="20000"
    Click="PasswordButtonClick" TabIndex="2"
    Style="{DynamicResource PassiveGlow}">
```

Comment: The Style applies to the whole Button, to target indivdual components (eg. `Borderbrush`) take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-the-opacity-of-an-element-or-brush

Comment: The only problem with this is that i wanted it to run constantly, even when the user hasn't clicked the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect using style described below :

```
<Style x:Key="PassiveGlow"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
       <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
       <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
       <Style.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation 
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Opacity"
                  From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:2" 
                  AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
              </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
         </EventTrigger>       
     </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This animation will start as soon as Button is loaded and will repeat forever as i have used Button.Loaded as the RoutedEvent and set RepeatBehavior to Forever. If you would like this animation to run only when the mouse enters the button for the first time , you can change the RoutedEvent to Button.MouseEnter. Also, Please note i didn't have the material style available while i tried this sample and hence i have added a new ControlTemplate for the button and got rid of BasedOn="{StaticResource GlowingButton}" part from style.

**To use a drop shadow effect instead of border :**

1. Add a setter for effect in style and set BorderThickness value to 0.

> ```
>     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
>     <Setter Property="Effect">
>         <Setter.Value>
>            <DropShadowEffect  ShadowDepth="5" Color="#7D00FE"/>
>         </Setter.Value>
>     </Setter>
> ```

2. Edit your Storyboard to target Effect.ShadowDepth property:

> ```
>   <Storyboard>
>       <DoubleAnimation 
>         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.ShadowDepth"
>         From="3.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:2" 
>         AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
>   </Storyboard>
> ```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much. I spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Is there anyway i can change it to DropShadowEffect ?

Comment: Edited answer to demonstrate how to animate DropShadowEffect  instead of border.